# AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"com.android.tools.r8.kotlin.H","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio

With the update of Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 | Patch 2, Kotlin 1.7.0, and Gradle being set yet as 7.4, we have this error with not so much info on how to resolve it.

Has anyone else experienced this exact error or have ideas where to look?

it also gives `Caused by: [CIRCULAR REFERENCE: com.android.tools.r8.kotlin.H]` error message at the end of the build output, but we have no circular dependencies within our app modules.

Comment: that one good developer who downvoted the question, I see that I "need more clarity", and I'd ask Android Studio devs for such clarity since we have no clue why the app does not build and gives only this line in the build output

Comment: it also gives me erorr`com.android.tools.r8.kotlin.H`
that's it

Comment: Please run you build with `./gradlew --stacktrace :app:assembleRelease` (replacing :app:assembleRelease with the failing target) to get a stack trace, if you cannot locate it in the IDE.

Answer (score 4):

Changing minimumSDK from 22 to 26 in project level build.gradle, solved my issue.

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdk 26
    targetSdk 33       
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same error. I solved it by changing the Gradle version in gradle-wrapper.properties and matching it with a compatible plugin version in project level build.gradle file

In project level build.gradle

```
 plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.2.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.2.2' apply false
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.3.15' apply false
}
```

In gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl = https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.2-bin.zip
```